# Is it possible to conditionally color countries in Mapbox Studio based on data?

Tags: mapbox, tilemill, cartocss

I am attempting to create a choropleth using the actual polygons included in any one of the base Mapbox maps.

Specifically, I have a geojson structure with a data specific property in the properties object and I'd like to have a different color land fill for all countries, depending on where the fall on a certain scale.

So far the Map class appears to color all land at once:

`Map {
  background-color: red;
}`

And I can't seem to do this:

`Map {
  [myVar > 0.4] { background-color: pink; }
  [myVar <= 0.4] { background-color: green; }
}`

I've tried to use my own polygons from my GeoJSON file but they aren't nearly as clean as the Mapbox polygons, even at the highest resolution I've found. Additionally, I want to be able to overlay the labels and other markers that Mapbox base styles have, just on top of my cholorpleth.

I've also tried to color the `#admin[admin_level=2][maritime=0]` regions, but they don't appear to be polygons and result in something like this:

[image: admin-2 areas fill fail]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you do a mockup of what you want the result would look like?

Comment: could you post a sample of your GeoJSON data?

Comment: Yes @mga. I am roughly trying to achieve this: https://i.gyazo.com/b56f3c1cfc55a313b8b3d5bc14151768.png

And I put some sample geoJSON here: https://gist.github.com/iros/e01aa4431e4d30f42ca8 

Note the `myVar` property. It's effectively the same, except I have a few of them and they are more meaningfully named ;). My goal is to generate raster tiles I can use with mapbox.js/leaflet.

Comment: GeoJSON file does not validate :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Tilemill 0.10.1 and using [this GeoJSON](https://gist.github.com/mgiraldo/92c69151bbc0c2338c8c) (imported as `countrydata`) and this CartoCSS:

```
#countrydata {
  line-color:#594;
  line-width:0.5;
  polygon-opacity:1;
  polygon-fill:#ae8;
  [2014_pop>=100000] {polygon-fill:@yellow;}
  [2014_pop>=10000000] {polygon-fill:@orange;}
  [2014_pop>=20000000] {polygon-fill:@pink;}
  [2014_pop>=200000000] {polygon-fill:@red;}
}
```

I get:

[image]

Notice how color is informed by the `2014_pop` property. I would recommend naming properties with a starting letter so that the editor doesn't get confused.

Comment: So, not quite. Yes, I can use that GeoJSON to render the polygons in it, but they aren't as high resolution: https://i.gyazo.com/ae56ca107a19280c6247ac4177509285.png

I would basically have to try and replicate the layout and data using my own GeoJSON.

Comment: This was a response I got so far: https://twitter.com/chieflybrit/status/636987450460475392

Comment: when you create a new map on TileMill with "default data" you get a base with high res polygons. you can download that dataset from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) and add whatever attributes you need for your map

Comment: It looks like that's the best option I have @mga. Thanks so much for looking into it.